# Sql Server Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Possuo a seguinte procedure

```
 PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAVL_Ignition]
        @DeviceIMEI VARCHAR(50),
        @TimeStamp SMALLDATETIME,
        @Value INT,
        @Tag VARCHAR(50)
    AS
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP (1) TimeStamp FROM AVL_Ignition)
            INSERT INTO  AVL_Ignition (DeviceIMEI, TimeStamp, Value)
            VALUES ('@DeviceIMEI', '@TimeStamp', '@Value')
        ELSE        
            DECLARE @LastValue INT = (SELECT CONVERT (int,Value)
                                      FROM AVL_Ignition
                                      WHERE TimeStamp = (SELECT MAX(TimeStamp) FROM AVL_Ignition))
            IF(@LastValue != @Value)
                    INSERT INTO  AVL_Ignition (DeviceIMEI, TimeStamp, Value)
                    VALUES ('@DeviceIMEI', '@TimeStamp', '@Value')
    END
```

Quando tento executar a procedure passando os parametros.

```
execute spAVL_Ignition 123, 2019-07-29 14:35:00, 1, null
```

O SQL Server aponta o seguinte erro.

> Sintaxe incorreta perto de '-'.

Também tentei fazer da seguinte forma.

```
execute spAVL_Ignition '123', '2019-07-29 14:35:00', '1', null
```

porém me apontou outro erro.

> A conversão falhou ao converter uma cadeia de caracteres para o tipo
>   de dados smalldatetime.

Qual seria a forma correta de passar a data por parâmetro ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa noite Gabriel.

O erro não ocorre por conta dos valores passados incorretamente nos parâmetros pois o segundo exemplo esta certo, mas sim porque esta escrevendo as variáveis como string.

**Incorreto**

```
VALUES ('@DeviceIMEI', '@TimeStamp', '@Value')
```

**Correto**

```
VALUES (@DeviceIMEI, @TimeStamp, @Value)
```

Segue uma breve correção no código:

```
 PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAVL_Ignition]
        @DeviceIMEI VARCHAR(50),
        @TimeStamp SMALLDATETIME,
        @Value INT,
        @Tag VARCHAR(50)
    AS
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP (1) TimeStamp FROM AVL_Ignition)
            INSERT INTO  AVL_Ignition (DeviceIMEI, TimeStamp, Value)
            VALUES (@DeviceIMEI, @TimeStamp, @Value)
        ELSE        
            DECLARE @LastValue INT = (SELECT CONVERT (int,Value)
                                      FROM AVL_Ignition
                                      WHERE TimeStamp = (SELECT MAX(TimeStamp) FROM AVL_Ignition))
            IF(@LastValue != @Value)
                    INSERT INTO  AVL_Ignition (DeviceIMEI, TimeStamp, Value)
                    VALUES (@DeviceIMEI, @TimeStamp, @Value)
    END
```